# How to make text go on right side of mui AppBar/Toolbar component?

Tags: css, material-ui, tailwind-css

How do I make the following menu bar the same but with the `log out` button on the right side?
[image]

Code:

```
    <main>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
        <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/")}>
            Home
          </Typography> 
          <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/projects")}>
            Projects
          </Typography> 
          <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/team")}>
            Goals
          </Typography> 
          {!session &&
            <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/login")}>
              Log in
            </Typography> 
          }
          {session &&
            <Typography  variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer right-0" onClick={() => signOut()}>
              log out
            </Typography> 
          }
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Toolbar />
    </main>
```

I am very tired as I have been struggling with this flippin' error for the past 1.5 hours

Comment: Are you using version 5 of material-ui ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add divs like this and use `justify-between` and `flex` to add space between them.

```
<main>
  <AppBar>
    <Toolbar>
       <div className="flex justify-between">
         <div>
          <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/")}>
        Home
      </Typography> 
      <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/projects")}>
        Projects
      </Typography> 
      <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/team")}>
        Goals
      </Typography> 
      {!session &&
        <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }} variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer" onClick={() => redirect("/login")}>
          Log in
        </Typography> 
      }
      </div>
      <div>
        {session &&
        <Typography  variant="h6" className="text-lg cursor-pointer right-0" onClick={() => signOut()}>
          log out
        </Typography> 
      }
      </div>
       </div>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
  <Toolbar />
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your CSS.
It will select the last `<Typography>` (which in your case is *log out*) in your `<Toolbar>` and send it to the rightmost side.

```
Toolbar Typography:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: @ProPoop please try the approach above and let me know in case you have any doubt/ clarification.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation is to utilize css flexbox. I group the three elements with a Box and implement CSS flexbox on it.

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Box, Toolbar, Typography } from "@mui/material";

function App() {
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flex: "1 1 0" }}>
          <Typography
            style={{ marginRight: 16 }}
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="text-lg cursor-pointer"
            // onClick={() => redirect("/")}
          >
            Home
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            style={{ marginRight: 16 }}
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="text-lg cursor-pointer"
            // onClick={() => redirect("/projects")}
          >
            Projects
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            style={{ marginRight: 16 }}
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="text-lg cursor-pointer"
            // onClick={() => redirect("/team")}
          >
            Goals
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        {/* session */}
        {false && (
          <Typography
            style={{ marginRight: 16 }}
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="text-lg cursor-pointer"
            // onClick={() => redirect("/login")}
          >
            Log in
          </Typography>
        )}
        {/* lets assume that session is true */}
        {true && (
          <Typography
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="text-lg cursor-pointer right-0"
            // onClick={() => signOut()}
          >
            log out
          </Typography>
        )}
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You may Interact my own implementation in the codesandbox just click **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-sea-1h7pb?file=/src/App.js)**